# document.execCommand('paste') returning "true"

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to develop a google chrome extension and part of it is `chrome.tabs.create( { url: "https://google.com/search?q=" +document.execCommand("paste") } );` and the link comes up as "https://google.com/search?q=true" Any help is great!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`execCommand('paste')` does not work that way. It does not return the contents of the clipboard, rather it does exactly what would happen if someone pressed Command+V or Control+V. It would paste the text whereever the text cursor is.

What you probably want to do in your extension is create a textarea in your extension's background HTML page, `focus` it, then execute the command. From there you can read the text from the textarea.

If you aren't familiar with background pages, you can get the details from [Chrome's Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html).

Using a background page is necessary because Chrome applies different sandbox restrictions to it. `execCommand('paste')` can only be used in more privileged places, like a background page.

You can use [`sendMessage`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html) to communicate between JS files and your background HTML page.

Comment: I am using a background page. That is the javascript in it. How would I use 'focus' with what im doing?